# correct output in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Problem guys is: rule CSS 'margin auto' with 'position absolute' does not work in IE7. Problem in IE7, all other browsers everything works fine. I have a parent element with 'position relative' it contains a child with 'position absolute'.  I need to align the element with 'position absolute' relative to the left and right sides of the parent.

```css
    .header {
      width: 100%;
      min-width: 1000px;
      position: relative;
      height: 341px;
    }

    .block-up {
      width: 100%;
      min-width: 1000px;
      background: #da251c;
      height: 341px;
    }

    .block-down {
      width: 100%;
      min-width: 1000px;
      background:  #585453;
      overflow: hidden;
      height: 341px;
    }

    /*problem areas*/
    
    .header-content {
      background: #ffffff;
      position: absolute;
      width: 493px;
      top: 150px;
      left: 10px;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      margin: auto;
      height: 341px;
    }
    /*problem areas*/

    .header-content-box {
      position: relative;
      width: 162px;
      float: left;
      border: 1px solid red;
      height: 341px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


    <div class="header">
      <div class="block-up">
      </div>
      <div class="block-down">
      </div>
      <div class="header-content">
        
        <div class="header-content-box">
           ......
        </div>
          
        <div class="header-content-box">
          ......
        </div>
            
        <div class="header-content-box">
          ......
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: IE7... ;/ ... Painful. Why you need `margin auto` with `position absolute`? Why you cant use position relative ?

Comment: because the unit is below 2 others when he should lie in the middle of two elements

Comment: OK i will test locally and see.. need to find IE7 emulator :D

Comment: look 'Run code snippet' and you will understand

Comment: Pogrindis, go to IE11 and press F12, select 'edge' -> 7

Comment: I have added a 'possible' solution.. But its ugly.

Answer (score 1):

The only possible `solution` I can think of is this..

```
.header-content {
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  display:block;
  width: 493px;
  top: 150px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left:-247px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 341px;
}
```

This will move left 50% and margin-left -50% of width.. Its painful and ugly.. But so is IE7..

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d128oc5j/)

```css
 .header {
      width: 100%;
      min-width: 1000px;
      position: relative;
      height: 341px;
    }

    .block-up {
      width: 100%;
      min-width: 1000px;
      background: #da251c;
      height: 341px;
    }

    .block-down {
      width: 100%;
      min-width: 1000px;
      background:  #585453;
      overflow: hidden;
      height: 341px;
    }

    /*problem areas*/
    
    .header-content {
      background: #ffffff;
      position: absolute;
      display:block;
      width: 493px;
      top: 150px;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left:-247px;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      /*margin:0 auto;*/
      height: 341px;
    }
    /*problem areas*/

    .header-content-box {
      position: relative;
      width: 162px;
      float: left;
      border: 1px solid red;
      height: 341px;
    
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<body>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="block-up">
      </div>
      <div class="block-down">
      </div>
      <div class="header-content">
        
        <div class="header-content-box">
           ......
        </div>
          
        <div class="header-content-box">
          ......
        </div>
            
        <div class="header-content-box">
          ......
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```